# CGLIB proxy not getting created for Transactional Proxies

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-transactions, cglib

Here is what I am doing:

```
@Component("jdbcBookDao")
public class JdbcBookDao extends JdbcDaoSupport implements BookDao{

@Autowired
public void injectDataSource(DataSource dataSource){
    setDataSource(dataSource);
}

@Transactional
public int getStock(int isbn){
    String sql = "SELECT bs.STOCK FROM BOOK b, BOOK_STOCK bs WHERE b.id=bs.book_id AND b.isbn=?";
    return getJdbcTemplate().queryForInt(sql, isbn);
}
}
```

And in the application context, I have declared:

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

With this config, I expected that when I fetch jdbcBookdao from context, it would be a CGLIB proxy(as I have set proxy-target-class to true). But when I debug, it comes as instance of JdkDynamicAopProxy. Can some one please explain why JDK proxy is getting created even when I requested for a CGLIB proxy?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't have any warning telling that CGLIB library classes are not found ?

Comment: I have CGLIB in my maven dependencies. Also I don't see any warnings in my log.

Comment: Can't see any reason why it wouldn't work then, maybe you miss something : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch08s06.html but from my point of view I don't see any

Comment: Tried to debug the Spring code. And here is what I observed. The proxy instantiation strategey is properly coming as CglibSubclassingInstantiationStrategy. This I have checked in AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory's instantiateBean() method.  Inside this instantiateBean, I see the code "Don't override the class with CGLIB if no overrides". Here the check "beanDefinition.getMethodOverrides().isEmpty()" fails and it created a JDK dynamic proxy. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Also observed that if I enable proxy-target-class through AOP Config, this is working perfect i.e.transactional cglib proxies are getting created. But if I don't have any AOP config and tried to enable CGLIB proxying using <tx:annotation-driven>, it is not working.

Comment: Interesting fact because documentation says : "To be clear: using 'proxy-target-class="true"' on <tx:annotation-driven/>, <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/> or <aop:config/> elements will force the use of CGLIB proxies for all three of them." but with what you've said it doesn't seem to be the case

Answer (score 0):

Spring source code into object according to you if you use interface then the JDK proxy, if you use normal class then the cgLib.

```
e   public AopProxy createAopProxy(AdvisedSupport config) throws AopConfigException {
    if (config.isOptimize() || config.isProxyTargetClass() || hasNoUserSuppliedProxyInterfaces(config)) {
        Class targetClass = config.getTargetClass();
        if (targetClass == null) {
            throw new AopConfigException("TargetSource cannot determine target class: " +
                    "Either an interface or a target is required for proxy creation.");
        }
        if (targetClass.isInterface()) {
            return new JdkDynamicAopProxy(config);
        }
        if (!cglibAvailable) {
            throw new AopConfigException(
                    "Cannot proxy target class because CGLIB2 is not available. " +
                    "Add CGLIB to the class path or specify proxy interfaces.");
        }
        return CglibProxyFactory.createCglibProxy(config);
    }
    else {
        return new JdkDynamicAopProxy(config);
    }
}nter code here
```

Comment: This is the default behavior. But we can override this by specifying the attrribute 'proxy-target-class' as 'true'